# Date-fns: how to get exact date output as moment ? e.g. put "th" after the day

Tags: node.js, date-fns

This is my test node.js code for comparison,
node 16.16.0,
"moment-timezone": "0.5.43",
"date-fns": "2.30.0",

```
const moment = require("moment-timezone");
const { intlFormat } = require('date-fns'); 

let d0 = moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
console.log(d0);

let d1 = intlFormat(new Date(), { dateStyle: 'full', timeStyle: 'medium' }, { locale: 'en-US', })
console.log(d1);
```

The output i get is

```
Monday, December 11th 2023, 3:55:27 pm
Monday, December 11, 2023 at 3:55:27 PM
```

So how to add "th" after 11 ? how to dislay pm not PM ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let d2 = format(d, "EEEE, MMMM do yyyy, h:mm:ss a");
console.log(d2);
```

The complete format is here
https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/format
Took me a while to find it, wish there's an easier way to find it for beginner.